# Change div color with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <div id="change" style="height:20px; width:100%; position: absolute; float:bottom; background-color:#000000">
</div> <br>
                <select name="bgcolor" id="bgcolor" onchange="colorDiv()"> 
                    <option class="1" value=1> Grey
                    <option class="2" value=2> White 
                    <option class="3" value=3> Blue
                    <option class="4" value=4> Cian
                    <option class="5" value=5> Green
                </select> <br><br>

<p id="demo"></p>       




<script>
function colorDiv(){
      var selection = document.getElementById('bgcolor');  
      var div = document.getElementById( 'change' );         
            div.style.backgroundColor='green';

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =selection; 

      switch (selection){
          case 1:
            div.style.backgroundColor='grey';
          case 2:
            div.style.backgroundColor='white';  
          case 3:
            div.style.backgroundColor='blue';
          case 4:
            div.style.backgroundColor='cian';
          case 5:
            div.style.backgroundColor='green';    
       }
</script>
```

Hi! I'm trying to change the background color of a div with js but it doesnt detect good the selected value, as i see when printing it on the parragraph. I've seen in multiple pages the procedure and it looks the same for me, but it actually does not work on my code. Can you see any mistakes?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Close your `option` tags.
2. Use `document.getElementById('bgcolor').value`
3. Don't forget to put `break` in each `case` or you will end up with green `div` everytime.
4. Use strings for your `case` conditions.

Amended Javascript:

```
function colorDiv() {
    var selection = document.getElementById('bgcolor').value;
    var div = document.getElementById('change');
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = selection;

    switch (selection) {
        case "1":
            div.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
            break;
        case "2":
            div.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            break;
        case "3":
            div.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
            break;
        case "4":
            div.style.backgroundColor = 'cian';
            break;
        case "5":
            div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            break;
    }
}
```

This [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kVvWv/6/) sums it up.

Comment: I took the liberty of copying your amended code into your post. JSFiddles are nice but please include the code in your answer as well.

Comment: @oGeez yeah, I agree, should've included it myself. Thank you

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev Use `cyan` instead of `cian`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the switch cases need a break statement after each one or the last one will be the one that you will see, in this case green. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="change" style="height:20px; background-color:#000000">
    change
</div>
<select name="bgcolor" id="bgcolor" onchange="colorDiv()"> 
    <option class="1" value="0"> Grey</option>
    <option class="2" value="1"> White </option>
    <option class="3" value="2"> Blue</option>
    <option class="4" value="3"> Cian</option>
    <option class="5" value="4"> Green</option>
</select>
<p id="demo"></p>       

<script>
function colorDiv(){
      var selection = document.getElementById('bgcolor').selectedIndex;
      var div = document.getElementById('change');
      div.style.backgroundColor='green';
      var colors = ["grey","white","blue","cian","green"];

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = colors[selection]; 

      switch (selection){
          case 0:
            div.style.backgroundColor='grey';
            break;
          case 1:
            div.style.backgroundColor='white';  
            break;
          case 2:
            div.style.backgroundColor='blue';
            break;
          case 3:
            div.style.backgroundColor='cian';
            break;
          case 4:
            div.style.backgroundColor='green';
            break;
        default:
            div.style.backgroundColor='purple';
       }
   };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; float:left;border:1px solid #000;" id="demo"></div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var latters = 'ABCDEF1234567890'.split("");
    var color = '#';
    for (var i=0; i < 6; i++)
    {
    color+=latters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];

    } 

    document.getElementById("demo").style.background = color ;

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer only contains code. You should actually explain what your code does to provide the OP with a good answer!